# Force Rails to not send an empty value of a text field if it is empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this field:

```
        <%= f.text_field :room, :class => 'span4', label: 'I work in', help: 'Work location. E.g., room or country or even address.', prepend: icon('briefcase'), disabled: !@can_set_room %>
```

Without touching it the browser sends an empty value for it to rails:

```
{"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "person"=>{"first_name"=>"Charlotte", "last_name"=>"Winkler", "room"=>""
```

How can I force rails to omit the `"room"->""` because that way my AR change will be:

```
person.changes: {room: [nil, ""]}
```

and I don't wan't that. I want to keep my AR untouched fields as nil.

Comment: If you are using rails 7.1 --> https://guides.rubyonrails.org/7_1_release_notes.html#add-activerecord-base-normalizes, otherwise use https://github.com/mdeering/attribute_normalizer

Comment: you can set zero-length strings to nil in a before_save callback

Comment: If you can be sure, pre-rendering, that this field won't be updated than you can set the field as readonly: true which will prevent it to be part of the requests params with an empty value.